# How to get HTML code inside Class using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Is it possible to get the whole HTML code inside div class `messageContent` Including HTML code itself?

[This](https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/) is the URL.

But I can't get the whole message and its format is that possible?
What I have tried is:

`item.css('div.messageContent blockquote::text').extract()`

```
<div class="messageContent">
<article>
<blockquote class="messageText SelectQuoteContainer ugc baseHtml">
Since I accidentally killed the 2018 thread, here&#039;s a cross-post of             
that fateful missive.<br />
<br />
Happy New Year, all! Here&#039;s to 2019, the year we see (my 
predictions...):<br />
<br />
<ul>
<li>The fabled $35k Tesla become reality</li>
<li>The Model Y (give it to me now!)</li>
<li>HW 3 and some minor FSD umbrella features (but definitely not FSD)        
</li>
<li>Tesla getting customer communications under control (where 
&#039;control&#039; indicates at least third-grader aptitude)</li>
<li>Elon doing something incredibly stupid</li>
</ul>What are your predictions?<br />
<br />
Enjoy!<br />
<br />
 <img 
  src="https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/attachments/fb_img_1546317769765- 
  jpg.365117/" class="bbCodeImage LbImage" alt="[&#x200B;IMG]" data- 
  url="https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/attachments/fb_img_1546317769765- 
  jpg.365117/" />
<div class="messageTextEndMarker">&nbsp;</div>
</blockquote>
</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can totally do that. The problem is that you are using `::text`, which indicates the selector to extract only the inner text inside the tags.

Use something like this:

```
item.css('div.messageContent blockquote').extract()
```

Which will return all the html inside the `blockquote` tag.